# php - how to give an admin their own section in panel?

Tags: php, database, roles

I have a little problem with my user/login panel in php. If guest comes to see my page in his panel he have options for login and register. Users see their member panel like below:

(there are some IF functions, which making sure that there's no session id in base, then showing options for guest)

```
                  <?php
        else:
        ?>

<div> 
<h1>Members panel</h1>
<p>You can put member-only data here</p>
<p><a href="registered.php">View a member page</a></p>           
<p><a href="changepass.php">Edit your password</a></p>
<p>-----</p>
<a href="?logoff">Log off</a>
```

Now: in my database with users  i have column named ROLE. There are roles like user and admin. I want to make admins see another section in that panel. I was trying with another switch/case and IF instruction, like:

```
                  <?php
                  if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] =='admin')); 
                  {    
                  }
                  ?>
                  (there is member panel) 
                  <div class="left right">      
        <h1>Administrator panel</h1>
        <a href="admin.php">View an admin page</a>
```

but it doesn't work. (I have session variable role.) Any ideas?

Comment: I'm not a `php` guy but could it be the `;` on the `if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] =='admin'));` line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all you should seperate view and control, i.e. do not put php code in your html files. there are plenty of possibilities to keep this much cleaner. the [SMARTY](http://www.smarty.net/) framework for instance is quite popular.

second, how is the role written to your $_SESSION (and why?). you should better pass your db-recordset. pseudo:

```
$rs = db->query(SELECT * FROM users ORDER BY userID)
if ($rs[&currentUserID]['role'] == 'admin') {
  ...
}
```

third: if you mess with php and html you should at least generate your php in a seperate area (obviously before any output) and output your HTML for instance with heredoc syntax:

```
<?php
  // do any PHP stuff here
  $panel = 'user logged in';
  if (admin) {
    $panel .= "i'm an admin";
  }
echo <<<OUT
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  ... // put all HTML in here and use variables

  <body>
    <div>$panel</div>
  </body>
</html>
OUT;
?>
```

PS: please remove the css tag as your question has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1):

You may try by removing the ';' after if

```
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] =='admin')) {    
?>
<!--ADMIN PANEL GOES HERE-->
<?php
    } else {
?>
<!---USER PANEL GOES HERE-->
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: Tried to do it like this:
<?php
  if (isset($_SESSION['role']) && ($_SESSION['role'] =='admin')) {    
?>
<!---USER PANEL GOES HERE-->
<!--ADMIN PANEL GOES HERE-->
<?php
    } else {
?>
<!---USER PANEL GOES HERE-->
<?php
    }
?>

and then endif (for others IF i suppose) 
And....don't have both of them now ;) BEFORE that changes i could see members page in admin account.

Comment: If you want to see users panel you must remove the 'else' statement with the braces '{' and '}' after it.